# why does my code say name 'count' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
words = input("Text: ")

def l_creator():
    count_char()
    count_sentences()
    print((count / sentence) * 100)

def count_char():
    count = 0
    for i in words:
        if i != ' ':
            count += 1  #number of words
    return count

def count_sentences():
    for i in words:
        a = words.split(' ') #number of sentences
    sentence = len(a) * 100
    return sentence


l_creator()
```

Why doesn't this code work? I've tried to use the keyword Global in other forms of the code and I've tried multiple accommodations of the code but just can't seem to get it right.

Is this the right form to call a function inside a function?

The terminal prompts:

```
File "read.py", line 32, in <module>
    l_creator()
  File "read.py", line 14, in l_creator
    count_char(count)
NameError: name 'count' is not defined
```

Comment: you need to save the return of your function calls to a variable like count = count_char() and sentence = count_sentences()

Comment: And then just divide count/ sentence?

Comment: It's worth noting that count within the count_char() function doesn't exist to the l_creator() function, it's not a global variable, it's local to the function itself, so if you don't assign it to a variable within the l_creator() function it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

An other solution is to add two lines in you code:
add to : count_char():

```
global count
```

and to count_sentences():

```
global sentence
```

Nb: in this case you don't need to "return " any thing from functions.